# How to get distinct values from array list in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql

In MySql database i have a product table with more columns :

catergories, model, color, size, price .

In Android app on `SplashActivity` i get te data from products table save it in a constant `ArrayList` and populate the `RecyclerView` with all product list.

How can i get distinct categories, distinct model, distinct color from this arraylist? I want to use those in dropboxes for filter the product list.

This is how i get the data from Mysql table and save it in `Constant.allProducts`,

```
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ProductMain>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ProductMain> call, Response<ProductMain> response) {
                    ProductMain main=response.body();
                    Constants.toateProdusele.clear();
                    Constants.toateProdusele.addAll(main.getProduse())
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                            finish();
                        }
                    },1500);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ProductMain> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,""+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            });
//and i populate the recyclerview
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.addAll(Constants.toateProdusele);
        adapter= new ProduseAdapter(HomePageActivity.this,  arrayList, ProductDetailActivity.class) ;
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What is the type of `Constants.toateProdusele`? `List<Object>`?

Comment: in  class Constants i have :public static List<Produse> toateProdusele=new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the stackoverflow.

Instead to save it in an `ArrayList<>` use a `HashSet<>` that will only save unique values,

If the list contains objects of classes defined in your code you will have to overwrite the `equals()` method in that class in order to distinguish which objects are different from each other and also the `hashcode()` method

Comment: how can i get HashSet from this array? i will need 3 HasSets one for categories ,one for model and one forcolor

Comment: Instead `public static List<Produse> toateProdusele=new ArrayList<>()` use `public static Set<Produse> toateProdusele=new HashSet<>()` but you will need you Override the method equals() for the class Produse

Comment: Note : OP should also override `Object::hashcode` and `Object::equals` of type `T` when using a `Set<T>` for unique value classes

Comment: I use hashset and now i have categories and color in this hashsets. How can i put one hashset in an list in an dialog ?

Comment: this is how i get data into hashset :  public void getFilter(List< Produse > allProduct){
            if (allProduct.size()>0){
                categorie.clear();
                for (int i=0;i<allProduct.size();i++){
                    categorie.add(allProduct.get(i).getCategorie());
                    culoare.add(allProduct.get(i).getCuloare());
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper example of `HashSet`, which will give you distinct values from an `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,2,2,3,5);

    System.out.println(numbers);

    Set<Integer> hashSet = new LinkedHashSet(numbers);
    ArrayList<Integer> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList(hashSet);

    System.out.println(removedDuplicates);
}
```